# Poisson probability question

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

**Accidents recur in a factory at the rate of 3 per week. Assume that accidents happen randomly and independently of each other.**

I've figured out:

**What is the probability of no accidents on a given day? Assume the factory works 7 days per week.**

$\frac{\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^0 e^{-\frac{3}{7}}}{0!}$

However, I'm not sure how to figure out the following:

```
What is the probability of there being 3 accident-free days in a week?
```

I'm trying something like:
$\left(\frac{1}{e^3}\right)^3 \left(1-\frac{1}{e^3}\right) \binom{7}{4}$

But I'm pretty sure im doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Exactly 3 or at least 3?

Answer (score 1):

Use $Y \sim Binomial(7, e^{-\frac{3}{7}})$

Comment: Hi, I tried using this to calculate the answer, but it didn't seem to be correct? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial%287%2C+e^-3%2F7%29&a=*C.binomial-_*ProbabilityDistribution-

Comment: 0.1428 is not the correct answer?

Comment: I actually have the answer for the case of 4 accidents per week, and the answer for that is .0053, I subbed in a different number and it didn't seem to be correct.

Comment: @Wilson can you show what equation you're using to obtain $0.0053$ ?

Comment: @Alex Will it be 7C3 (e-3/7)^4 (1 - e-3/7)^3? I'm getting an answer of 0.26 approximately. Also, Why are we using a negative 3/7? Shouldn't it be positive?